# Git Fatal Error when using Graphics Magick convert command

Tags: git, command-line, graphicsmagick

When I try to use a Graphics Magick command, (something simple, just to test the program) I cannot do anything, as it always replies back with a git error.

```
gm convert
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I did not put any particular action, as nothing works

Comment: Does `alias gm` print anything interesting ?

Comment: `gm='git merge'` I guess if I remove it from my aliases, it will work correctly, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [Marth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650437/marth) I found my problem. 
I have intalled oh-my-zsh because I really love the customization and auto-complete features, but I don't usually use Git, so I'm not familliar with the feautres it has. Oh-my-zsh comes with a git plugin with some aliases pre-built, and there was my problem.

Thanks for your help, Marth!

Answer (score 7):

You may have installed oh-my-zsh.
In the oh-my-zsh, there is 'gm'(git merge alias)

So, you have to modify alias, in file

> ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh

find `gm` keyword and modify to different name.